# Nodejs find user and delete image with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What I am trying to do is find the user by email and delete an item from an array.

What is the right way to do that?

So here is my code:

````
 Accomodation.findOneAndDelete(
   { email: req.session.passport.user },
   { images: req.body.imageSelected },
   function (error, result) {
     if (error) {
     } else {
       console.log(result);
     }
   }
 );
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it:

```
app.post("/accomodation-imgdelete", (req, res, next) => {
  Accomodation.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: req.session.passport.user },
    { $pull: {images: 2},
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    })
});
```